# Use js.erb file to rename td instead of replace it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got a page that toggles fields back and forth on button presses.  So far, my only solution is to put a nested td inside the original one making the page look bad.  You can see the tunnel effect of tds within tds:

[image: Ugly formatting]

Is there a way to rename the containing td instead of putting a new one inside it.  I have to swap the functionality each time so it's necessary to rename them.  Here's the js.erb for each:

remove.js.erb:

```
<% if @pos_range %>
    <% @pos_range.each do |p|%>
        $("td#remove_name_<%= p %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'some_partial'))%>");
        $("td#remove_button_<%= p %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'some_partial_2'))%>");
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    $("td#remove_name_<%= @td_num %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'some_partial'))%>");
    $("td#remove_button_<%= @td_num %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'some_partial_2'))%>");
<% end %>
```

update.js.erb:

```
<% @pos_range.each do |p|%>
    $("td#add_device_<%= p %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'some_other_partial', :locals => { :id => @id, :position_str => @position_str} ))%>");
    $("td#add_device_button_<%= p %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'some_other_partial_2', :locals => { :id => @id, :position_str => @position_str} ))%>");
<% end %>
```

And here are the html.erb files:

some_partial:

```
<td id=<%="add_device_#{@i.to_s}"%>>
    Nothing assigned
</td>
```

some_partial_2:

```
<td id=<%="add_device_button_#{@i.to_s}"%>>
    <%= link_to "Change", {:controller => :some_controller, :action => :show, :id => @id, :position => @i }, :remote => true, :class => "btn" %>
</td>
```

some_other_partial:

```
<td id=<%="remove_name_#{@i.to_s}"%>>
    <%= @position_str %>&nbsp;
</td>
```

some_other_partial_2:

```
<td id=<%="remove_button_#{@i.to_s}"%>>
    <%= link_to "Remove", { :controller => :some_controller, :action => :remove, :id => @id, :position => @i}, :remote => true, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the jQuery command `.html` replaces the content of the selector with new content. What you want is to replace the entire node

```
    $("td#remove_name_<%= p %>").replaceWith("<%= j render partial: 'some_partial' %>");
```

Here's a working example showing you: http://jsfiddle.net/K4c9x/

Comment: Thanks @JesseWolgamott, works perfectely.  Pretty simple solution, but I appreciate it.  I'm new to jquery.